# Partition data in N parts considering a grouping variable R

Tags: r, dplyr, mapreduce, data-wrangling

Is there a function that would partition a grouped df into a list of N elements ensuring the observations in a group end up on the same partition?

basically, the same way `multidplyr::partition` works.

Comment: Something like https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html?

Comment: Yes, exactly like group_split. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group_split` accomplishes this exact functionality.